# How to properly determine number of vibrational modes of CO in carbonyl complexes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

it's been a few years since I took inorganic chemistry and was starting to refresh some of the concepts. What I didn't really understood when I reread was the following: How to properly determine the number of vibrational modes of CO in carbonyl complexes.

I always understood the vibration of CO as the streching of the C-O-bond as in the diatomic molecule, *disregarding* the M-C bond; so only the internuclear distance of C and O changes and so does the dipole moment. That is the premise; is that correct?

Also, I recall that one can only see the asymmetric strech of CO when bound in a trans-fashion to the metal center, because the symmetric strech won't change the dipole moment. How come then that this strech on the left is IR-active:

[image]

As the C-O bonds both enlargen, the dipole moments should cancel? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't that because the left molecule is polar, and right one is not. Because the first molecule is polar, any vibration will be IR active. Just like in water.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177246/how-to-properly-determine-number-of-vibrational-modes-of-$\chem{CO}$-in-carbonyl-complexes

Comment: That is the same question..

Comment: @Mäßige-Yes that may be right my friend, but here you have to make one thing, there is one part of this particular title which has to be changed into $\ce{CO}$ ASAP

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177246/how-to-properly-determine-number-of-vibrational-modes-of-co-in-carbonyl-complexes

Comment: @Mäßige-You have to change the link given in the comment which I posted here on Jan 15 at 7:08 to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177246/how-to-properly-determine-number-of-vibrational-modes-of-$\ce{CO}$-in-carbonyl-complexes prior to deleting the other comment that was posted on this website in the same day on 12:13

Answer (score -2):

You are completely right in your thinking. Only assymetric stretching can be seen in IR spectroscopy, and this is exactly reflected by the diagram. The left part shows stretching above and below Me center, these cancel out; but on the rear there are 2 CO molecules contributing to the change of dipole moment.